# $\lim$ vs $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ in the proof of convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution

Tags: limits, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

I am studying the various types of convergence for random variables, in particular how convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution.

Let $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of random variables and let us assume that $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$. After some computations, we can write:
$$F_X(t-\epsilon) - P(|X_n - X|> \epsilon) \le F_{X_n}(t) \le F_X(t+\epsilon) + P(|X_n - X|> \epsilon) $$
where $F_X(t)$ is the CDF of $X$ and $\epsilon > 0$.

At this point I don't understand why several authors (e.g. [example of proof](https://nptel.ac.in/courses/108106083/lecture28_Convergence.pdf)) use $\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty}$ and $\liminf \limits_{n \to \infty}$ to show that the limit of $F_{X_n}(t)$ is bounded by $F_X(t-\epsilon)$ and $F_X(t+\epsilon)$ for $n \to \infty$; in particular they write:
$$F_X(t-\epsilon) \le \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \mbox{inf } F_{X_n}(t) \le \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \mbox{sup } F_{X_n}(t) \le F_X(t+\epsilon)$$
and then they conclude the proof by resorting to the continuity of $F_X(t)$.

My question is, why is it not sufficient to just compute the limits of the elements of the inequality above obtaining $F_X(t-\epsilon) \le \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} F_{X_n}(t)\le F_X(t+\epsilon)$ ? In particular we can define:
$$a_n := F_X(t-\epsilon) - P(|X_n - X|> \epsilon)$$
$$b_n :=F_X(t+\epsilon)+ P(|X_n - X|> \epsilon)$$ for all $n$, then knowing that $a_n \le F_{X_n}(t) \le b_n$, from one of the comparison theorems for sequences and the converge in probability of $X_n$, we obtain:
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = F_X(t-\epsilon) \le \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} F_{X_n}(t)\le \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = F_X(t+\epsilon)$$

Am I missing anything?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because $\lim_{n}F_{X_{n}}(t)$ does not have to exist for all $t$.

Consider, for example, a random variable $X_{n}$ which takes the value $\frac{1}{n}(-1)^{n}$ almost surely.
Clearly, this converges in probability to a random variable $X$ which is zero almost surely.
To see this, let $\epsilon>0$ and note that for all $n\geq1/\epsilon$,
$$
\mathbb{P}(\left|X_{n}-X\right|>\epsilon)=\mathbb{P}(\left|X_{n}\right|>\epsilon)=0.
$$
Meanwhile, $F_{X_{n}}(0)$ is zero when $n$ is even and one when it is odd.
Therefore, despite being bounded between zero and one, its limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ does not exist.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer :)
I get your point but then I am misunderstanding the definition of convergence in distribution. How should we read it, 1) if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} F_{X_n}(t)$ exists then the equality  $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} F_{X_n}(t)=F_X(t)$ must hold or 2)  $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} F_{X_n}(t)$ must exist and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} F_{X_n}(t)=F_X(t)$ must hold? Until now I have been thinking we are in case 1, so for me the existence of such limit was an assumption. But if we are in case 2, then we have to prove its existence.

Comment: @zeroKnowl: It's actually neither (1) nor (2). The limit has to hold at points of continuity of $F_X$. I added the definition and some further elaboration to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time you spent on this answer, everything is clear now :)

Comment: @parsiad $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} F_{X_n}(t)$ as given in your example exists and is equal to 0.   reference----->https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4207905/415432

Comment: @abhishek: Don't know what I was thinking. Fixed.