# Doubt on the limit of a sequence of functions

Tags: limits, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

This question is a doubt I had while reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3123969/415432) answer.

The answer poster, of the linked answer says that $\lim_n F_{X_n}(0)$ does not exist, where $F_{X_n}(\cdot)$ is defined as follows:

$F_{X_{n}}(t)=0\cdot\boldsymbol{1}_{(-\infty,0)}(t)+tn\cdot\boldsymbol{1}_{[0,1/n)}(t)+1\cdot\boldsymbol{1}_{[1/n,\infty)}(t)
=\begin{cases} 0,~\text{if}~ -\infty< x <0\\
               nx, ~\text{if}~ 0\leq x\leq 1/n\\
                1,  ~\text{if} ~1/n\leq x\leq \infty
\end{cases}
$

But, since  $F_{X_n}(0)=0, \forall n$, hence  $\lim_n F_{X_n}(0)=0$, hence  $\lim_n F_{X_n}(0)$ exists.

Did I do something wrong?

If yes then what is it, and if no, could you give an example of a sequence of functions  $F_{n}$ such that  $\lim_n F_{n}(x)$ does not exist for some $x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ take the values $0$ and $1$ with probabilty $\frac 1  2$ each. Let $X_n=X+\frac 1 n$ if $n$ is even and $X-\frac  1 n=$ if $n$ is odd. Then $X_n \to X$ in probability, $P(X_n \leq 0)=0$ for $n$ even and $P(X_n \leq 0)=\frac 1 2$ for $n$ odd. So $\lim P(X_n \leq 0)$ does not exist.

Comment: What mistake did that answer poster make? Also, that answer poster has written that $\lim_{n}F_{X_{n}}(t)$ does not have to exist for all $t$. Could you give an example of such a function

Comment: @abhishek I have edited my answer.